# NamedParameterJdbcOperations escape apostrophe in like

Tags: java, spring

I have a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE MODULE = :moduleId AND 
UPPER(NAME) LIKE UPPER('%sample''s%') AND ID = :userId;
```

I escape the apostrophe above with ''.  Then pass the sql above to...

```
Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
paramMap.put("userId", userId);

namedParameterJdbcOperations.queryForList(sql, paramMap, Long.class);
```

and I got this error:

SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 3; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 3

when looking at the logs, I saw the that the userId was not being replaced by ?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE MODULE = ? 
AND UPPER(NAME) LIKE UPPER('%sample''s%') AND ID = :userId;
```

Comment: Can you make `'%sample''s%'` a parameter as well and put it in the `paramMap` with value `%sample's%`? That way, you let JDBC do the apostrophe escaping and it might prevent the SQL-error.

Comment: Can u give an example of a string that can fit into '%sample''s%'. I mean you would have a record in db.

Comment: Yes, we have a record in db with "Sample's".  The whole criteria "AND UPPER(NAME) LIKE UPPER('%sample''s%')" is composed in another function, so i cannot just put the value as parameter, this whole string is concatenated to the rest of the sql